'Chroma' object has no attribute 'persist'
I'm persisting the Chroma Database but it's giving me an error.
I'm basically redoing what's in this link.
https://github.com/hwchase17/chroma-langchain/blob/master/persistent-qa.ipynb
Is there any update in chromadb version and they have removed persist I don't get it.
!pip -q install chromadb openai langchain tiktoken

!pip install -q langchain-chroma

!pip install -q langchain_chroma  langchain_openai langchain_community

from langchain_chroma import Chroma
from langchain_openai import OpenAI
from langchain_community.embeddings import OpenAIEmbeddings
from langchain_community.document_loaders import TextLoader
from langchain_community.document_loaders import DirectoryLoader

persist_directory ='db'

embedding = OpenAIEmbeddings()

vectordb = Chroma.from_documents(documents=texts,
                                 embedding=embedding,
                                 persist_directory=persist_directory)

vectordb.persist()

Then I'm getting the below error:


AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[47], line 1
1 vectordb.persist()
AttributeError: 'Chroma' object has no attribute 'persist'


Did you find a solution to this issue?

In newer versions the documents are automatically persisted.
You just need to update the import. Where you import Chroma, use this:
from langchain_chroma import Chroma

And delete the persist in your code.

The following import solved the problem
from langchain_community.vectorstores.chroma import Chroma

persist_directory = "/tmp/chromadb"
vectordb = Chroma.from_documents(documents=texts, embedding=embeddings,
                                 persist_directory=persist_directory)
vectordb.persist()

I too was unable to find the persist() method in the earlier import
from langchain_community.vectorstores import Chroma


Try this
from langchain_community.vectorstores import Chroma
persist_directory = "/tmp/chromadb"
vectordb = Chroma.from_documents(documents=texts, embedding=embeddings,
                                 persist_directory=persist_directory)
vectordb.persist()



Since Chroma 0.4.x the manual persistence method is no longer supported as docs are automatically persisted. So you can just get rid of vectordb.persist() and it will work fine

The class Chroma was deprecated in LangChain 0.2.9 and will be removed in 0.4. An updated version of the class exists in the langchain-chroma package and should be used instead. To use it run pip install -U langchain-chroma and import as from langchain_chroma import Chroma.


